# Three.js - First Child Jumps and Adopts Parent Transforms

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a parent/child hierarchy between three objects using the ".add()" method in Three.js, (RE: 71). Parenting a two objects poses no problems. However, When I attempt to create a three level hierarchy, the middle child jumps to an offset equivalent to the offset of it's parent from the origin.

This is the hierarchy:

Red Box (parent of Green Box) -> Green Box (parent of Blue Box) -> Blue Box

Below is an image of how the boxes should be positioned before and after the parenting:
[image]

This is an Image if how the boxes have been repositioned when parented:
[image]

The relevant code looks like this:

```
        var testObject_G1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 100, 100);
        var testObject_G2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 50);
        var testObject_G3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 100, 100);

        var testObject_MR = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
        var testObject_MG = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var testObject_MB = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });

        var testObject_Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(testObject_G1, testObject_MR);
        testObject_Mesh.position.x = -100;

        var testObject_Mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(testObject_G2, testObject_MG);
        testObject_Mesh2.position.x = 0;

        var testObject_Mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(testObject_G3, testObject_MB);
        testObject_Mesh3.position.x = 100;

        testObject_Mesh2.add( testObject_Mesh3 );
        testObject_Mesh.add( testObject_Mesh2 );

        scene.add( testObject_Mesh );
```

There is a JS Fiddle here: [jumping second child](http://jsfiddle.net/SkyBurchard/ju1ochLv/10/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you see is correct. In a hierarchy the child will inherit the parents transform (inherit is simplification; their matrices will be multiplied but you only have translation defined so the values will be added). So testMesh (red) will appear at x=-100, testMesh2 (green) will also appear at x=-100 (since its x transform is 0 and will inherit its parent transform) and testMesh3 (blue) will appear at x=0 (since -100+0+100=0).

Add this to your fiddle to see the relative transformations.

```
scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 ));
```

Comment: So by this logic, if I want to keep my hierarchy as it is and achieve the results I'm after, I would want to make the position of the second child equal to the difference of it's current position and it's parents position: (0 - -100 = 100). i.e the second child's position would be set to x= 100.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand. Did you achieve what you are after? you fiddle is working as you want?

Comment: Yes, Thank you gaitat.